# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f110002

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

When trying to open a preferences activity I sometimes get ad error and the app crashes. The problem is that I don't have any idea why this sometimes happens and sometimes not.
From my point of view the code itself seems to be correct. When I add for example a `System.out.println(android.R.id.content);` after `setupActionBar();`
I usually get this error on the emulated Nexus 9 (Android 6.0, API 23).

```java
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();

        // if I add ex. System.out.println(android.R.id.content); it works.

        // load settings fragment
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
                new SettingsPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
     */
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || SettingsPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class SettingsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

```java
public abstract class AppCompatPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDelegate().installViewFactory();
        getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
        getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return getDelegate().getMenuInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().addContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        getDelegate().onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
        super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
        getDelegate().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        getDelegate().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getDelegate().onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getDelegate().onDestroy();
    }

    public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
        getDelegate().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
        if (mDelegate == null) {
            mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
        }
        return mDelegate;
    }
}
```

when opening this activity the error I get looks like this:

```
W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f110002, entry index(2) is beyond type entryCount(1)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f110002 (t=16 e=2) (error -75)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.*****.app, PID: 14679
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.*****.app/de.*****.app.SettingsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f110002
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f110002
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2774)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:1214)
        at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.loadHeadersFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:810)
        at de.*****.app.SettingsActivity.onBuildHeaders(SettingsActivity.kt:56)
        at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:596)
        at de.*****.app.AppCompatPreferenceActivity.onCreate(AppCompatPreferenceActivity.kt:23)
        at de.*****.app.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.kt:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Application terminated.
```

Hopefully someone has an idea, what the problem might be.

Comment: where you are replacing your setting fragment ? i mean you have `fragment` in your layout ?

Comment: The error occurs when calling `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsPreferenceFragment()).commit();`

Comment: @oivlis111 there is an issue in your resource file. I believe you are assigning wrong id to the fragment. Or the id is not there in the first place. Can you post your xml code too from where you are getting the ID.

Comment: It's the code directly after AppCompatPreferenceActivity. The other XML is just the default string, style, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I actually found the problem. When reading the error message very carefully I noticed that it references on a Kotlin file - but I use Java.
Because cleanup and rebuild did not work I copied the Java code, converted the file to Kotlin, removed the Kotlin file and recreated the Java file. Now everything work's fine.

Answer (score 0):

did you add this res/xml/preference_headers.xml in resource directory?

Comment: I thought I don't need that file because I don't reference on that.

Answer (score 0):

> you are doing great but the problem is here.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

you are calling finish before executing the super method, all you have to do is that replace with this.

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
} 

uninstall the application and then reinstall.
```